# .NET framework compatible with Azure and Windows Server

Tags: .net, azure

I'm moving a piece of code to a Service Role in Azure.

I had to tweak some parts to make them work with Azure, I was expecting some but now there are many and code is not compatible with original version anymore.

My plan is to deploy this service on a hybrid environment cloud/own servers so Is there any .NET framework that I can use to adapt my code and able to work on both cloud and my own servers?

Comment: How will you be deploying your application in Azure  - Web Apps, Cloud Services or Virtual Machines?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Service Role"? Web/worker role in a Cloud Service/ Service Fabric?

Comment: @GauravMantri  code will be deployed as a Cloud Service, a WebRole to be more specific.

Comment: @davvidmakogon webrole

Answer (score 0):

@GBrian, I think you don't need to worry about compatibility issues for .NET framework with Azure Cloud Service and Windows Server.

Only need thinking is that which services you need on Azure, please refer to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-choose-me/) to make your choice and refer to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/) to get started.

Using Visual Studio to migrate the on-premise application to Azure Cloud Service is easier. There are two articles which can help guiding for you, please see below.

1. [How to: Migrate and Publish a Web Application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service/)
2. [Migrate Existing ASP.NET Website to Azure Cloud Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikerichter/2015/12/10/migrate-existing-asp-net-website-to-azure-cloud-services/)